# escape single quotes in sql query while passing as variable to python

Tags: php, amazon-athena, pyathena

I am trying to query athena using php. My code is as below which works.

PHP

```
<?php
$sql2Py = "'SELECT address,order,status from myDB.order;'";
$output = shell_exec("python3 pythonScript.py $sql2Py");
echo "my result-" . $output;
?>
```

pythonScript.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from pyathena import connect
import pandas

sql = str(sys.argv[1])
orders = pandas.read_sql(sql,conn) 
print (orders)
```

How do I escape the quotes while adding a string to the query? I tried using backslash like below but this does not work.

```
$sql2Py = "'SELECT address,order,status from myDB.order where status <> \'Completed\';'";
```

Comment: And you have to put the single quotes on each side of your SQL query...?

Comment: If I remove the quotes it does not work

Comment: I tried moving the quotes to the python script too but then python treats it like a string instead of a variable->    orders = pandas.read_sql('sql',conn)

Comment: Do notice the duplicate linked at the top, which provides the solution…!

Comment: thanks all, escapeshellarg did the trick